# Using Modal Dialog in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to open a modal dialog.

I have a modal.blade.php in `myproject/vendor/laracasts/flash/src/views/modal.blade.php`

Which containts the following code:

```
<div id="flash-overlay-modal" class="modal fade {{ $modalClass or '' }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ $title }}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{!! $body !!}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to call this and use this to open a modal dialog.

I can easily make modal dialog with jQuery, CSS, etc following any tutorials but I need to somehow use this blade template in this project and I am not entirely sure how.

Any help?

Comment: Why not to put this peice of code inside resouces/view dir????

Comment: @MahaDev Undefined variable... This seems to be some sort of plug in but I am not entirely sure which one so I cannot look up how to use it.

Comment: This required bootstrap js and bootstrap css. Did u inlcude them properly.?